# Handle third-party web service timeout from asp.net code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

What is the right way to handle a web service timeout when called from asp.net server-side code?

For years, I've called various web services from my asp.net server code -- services for shipment rating, address verification, payment processing, etc. Usually those services return a response in a timely manner.

I now have a requirement to call a different external service.  That service can occasionally go down in a way that causes it to never return a response.  My code dutifully waits, and the users' web requests time out as a result.

I don't want to extend the timeout period of a request.  It's already at 60 seconds, which normally is *way* over the needed time.

I tried spawning a thread to call the external web service, with its own timeout that I can control and handle.  This kind of works, but after the thread's timeout is caught and handled, my application catches a ThreadAbortException.  What, if anything, should I do about that?

Comment: how are you calling this external service (i.e. in asp.net click events? ).

Comment: The service is called on page load when IsPostBack is false, but only if needed. The service's response is stored in the database so it's not called multiple times unnecessarily.